# Mongoengine : How to update specific fields of an existing document?

Tags: flask, mongoengine, marshmallow

I have an existing mongo document which has been exposed over a REST API. The API request will contain certain fields from the document which either needs to be updated with new values or insert new values in them if the field is null. How to perform the update on fields of an existing mongoengine document? I'm using marshmallow-mongoengine for serialization on flask.

The problem that I'm facing is that if a certain field is missing in the request payload, on calling update with the remaining fields as kwargs leads to setting the missing fields as None. How can update or insert only the fields given in the payload?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Joseph's answer is OK. But another answer wont hurt eh!

Here's how i updated my document using flask-mongoengine

Actual code :

```
Game.objects(id = _id).update(
        set__kickoff = request_json.get('kickoff'),
        set__gameid = request_json.get('gameid'),
        set__home_team = request_json.get('home_team'),
        set__away_team = request_json.get('away_team'),
        set__home_win = request_json.get('home_win'),
        set__draw = request_json.get('draw'),
        set__away_win = request_json.get('away_win'),
        set__sport = request_json.get('sport')
        )

Game class : 

    import datetime
    flask_mongoengine import BaseQuerySet, MongoEngine
    db = MongoEngine()

    class Game(db.Document):
    kickoff  = db.DateTimeField(required=True)
    added_on  = db.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.utcnow)
    gameid = db.FloatField(required=True)     
    home_team = db.StringField(required=True)
    home_win = db.FloatField(required=True)    
    draw = db.FloatField(required=True)
    away_win = db.FloatField(required=True)
    away_team = db.StringField(required=True)
    sport = db.StringField(required=True) 
    meta = {
        'collection':'games',
        'queryset_class': BaseQuerySet
    }
```

PS : Remember to indent the code in python

**Additionally I noticed you tagged Marshmallow in your question. Here, a sample derived from their official git repo** [here](https://github.com/touilleMan/marshmallow-mongoengine/blob/master/docs/tutorial.rst)

> First we need a Mongoengine Document:

```
import mongoengine as me

class Task(me.EmbeddedDocument):
    content = me.StringField(required=True)
    priority = me.IntField(default=1)


class User(me.Document):
    name = me.StringField()
    password = me.StringField(required=True)
    email = me.StringField()
    tasks = me.ListField(me.EmbeddedDocumentField(Task))
```

> Great ! Now it's time for the Marshmallow Schema. To keep things DRY, we use marshmallow-mongoengine to do the mapping:

```
import marshmallow_mongoengine as ma

class UserSchema(ma.ModelSchema):
    class Meta:
        model = User
```

> Finally it's time to use our schema to load/dump documents:First let's create a document

```
user_schema = UserSchema()
u, errors = user_schema.load({"name": "John Doe", "email": 
      "jdoe@example.com", "password": "123456","tasks": [{"content": "Find a 
      proper password"}]})
u.save()
```

> If the document already exists, we can update it using update

```
u
u2, errors = user_schema.update(u, {"name": "Jacques Faite"})
>>> u2.name
"Jacques Faite"
```

Comment: The marshmallow update bit is exactly what I am looking for. Thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help. :-)

Comment: I think you did the same mistake that Marshmallow-mongoengine docs also do. Its `user_schema` and not `user.schema` in the last two code snippets.

Comment: i am returning the response to frontend from backend of flask after updating, but it is not returning the Latest mongodb object, what is the solution

Comment: @ChampR How can we update many documents(Not all) with different values for name using marshmallow mongoengine.

Answer (score 2):

If you only want to update one single document you can use the save method.  That's what I do.  If a document already exists, it updates fields instead of creating a new document.

```
car = Car.objects(pk=car_id) # return a queryset
if car:     
    car = car.get(pk=car_id) # return an object from queryset
    car.make = requestData['make']
    car.model = requestData['model']
    car.mileage = requestData['mileage']
    car.save()
```

If you want to update many documents then, I recommend checking out the [atomic updates](http://docs.mongoengine.org/guide/querying.html#atomic-updates) section of the user guide.

Something like~

```
Car.objects(param="param to filter by").update(set__param=newParam)
```

"set" followed by two underscores is a modifier.  There are more modifiers available in the guide I linked above.

Comment: I want to use the response as it is and not perform atomic updates one by one. Is there a way out?

Comment: Not exactly sure what you mean.  To be clear, how many documents are you updating at a time?  If 1, then you could use the first example, if many than the second example.  The save method will not create a new document if it already exists.  It will update it.  You don't have to reassign every value.  In your request you can send empty string or default value for unassigned parameters.

Comment: @JosephVargas How can we update many documents(Not all) with different values for a field "name" using marshmallow mongoengine.